# Application to help writing EF POCO class by using Sql Server Managment Studio

Tags: ef-code-first

For a new project I want to use Entity Framework code first to design entities. However, I can design tables much more intuitively using Sql Server Management studio. Is there a technique or application that allows me to go back and forth between SSMS and the Visual Studio editor and helps me end up with a completed POCO class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "go back and forth between SSMS and the Visual Studio editor", but you can design all your tables from SSMS and then create model classes automatically (scaffold models and DbContext)
If you're using `dotnet core`, first install following Nuget packages,

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

Now open `Package Manager Console` on VS and run, (Change `Server` name and `Database`)

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.;Database=SampleDb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

This will create all the model classes in `Models` folder. Now from this point onward you can carryon with code-first approach.

If you're using `.NET Framework`, create a folder named `Models` in you're project, then right click on the project -> click `Add New Item`.

[image]

Search for `ADO.NET Data Entity Model`, give a proper name and click `Add`

[image]

In the next dialog you can select the 4th option, `Code first from database`

[image]

After that click `New connection` and configure your connection.

[image]

In the next page select tables and/or views and click `Finish`.

[image]

Your models classes should be available now.
Again, **please remeber that from this point onward you can't use SSMS to design tables**, because it will throw exceptions fron Entity Framework. Read more [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database).